# Rendering doesn't work after setState is called

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am a beginner to react Js.Currently ,I am working on a website with react Js on frontend.I am stucked at a point which retrieves some data from the server.This is **not a problem with cors**.I already performed many requests successfully from frontend.This is the postman request and the response.[image]

Here my Spring Boot Backend returns a **HashMap<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>>** response with only one element.

Here is my react js code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "../components/navbar";
import "../css/timetable.css";
import "../components/timetableSupport";
import SingleEvent from "../components/singleEvent";
import "../css/home.css";
import bgImage from "../images/bg4.jpg";
import axios from "axios";

let FIND_LEC_SCHEDULE_URL = "/schedule/findscheduledetailsbylecturer/";
let weekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
let times = ["08:00","08:30","09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30", "15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30",
  "17:00",];
class TimeTable extends React.Component {
  state = {loading : false}

  componentDidMount() {
    const auth = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
    FIND_LEC_SCHEDULE_URL += localStorage.getItem("lid");

    axios
      .get(FIND_LEC_SCHEDULE_URL, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: auth,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response data = ',response.data);

        this.setState(
        {
          timeTable: response.data.result
        },
        () => {
          console.log('timeTable = ',this.state.timeTable);
          this.setState({ loading: true });
        }
      );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error =", error);
      });
    
  }

  createSchedule = (dayIndex) => {
    let tmp = this.state.timeTable[dayIndex];

    return tmp.map((schedule) => (
      <SingleEvent
        key={dayIndex}
        start={schedule[0]}
        end={schedule[1]}
        eventType={schedule[2]}
        eventName={schedule[3]}
        roomNo={schedule[4]}
      ></SingleEvent>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar pageName="Time table"></NavBar>
        {this.state.loading === true ? (
          <div>
            <img src={bgImage} className="homeloginImg"></img>
            <div>
              <br />

              <div className="tt-outer">
                <div className="cd-schedule loading ">
                  <div className="timeline">
                    <ul>
                      {times.map((time, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                          <span>{time}</span>
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div className="events">
                    <ul className="wrap">
                      {weekDays.map((day, index) => (
                        <li key={index} className="events-group">
                          <div className="top-info">
                            <span>{day}</span>
                          </div>
                          <ul>{this.createSchedule(index)}</ul>
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div className="cover-layer"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Still Loading</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default TimeTable;
```

In package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

Here is the output in browser console.[image]

Clearly I am getting the response with no errors.

But in the website I am not getting the expected output from above react js code.(I expect to get the timetable details from the server and show it on the website.Here I only see empty timetable)

But unexpectedly, When I copy the postman response and set it as the **this.state.timeTable** ,**website gives the expected output.**

I did only this change in **ComponentDidMount**.

```
componentDidMount() {
    //this is copied from postman api response
    let arr = [
      [
        ["13:00", "14:00", "event-1", "GP106", "lecture room 19"],
        ["08:00", "09:00", "event-1", "GP106", "lecture room 10"],
      ],
      [
        ["09:00", "11:00", "event-1", "CO321", "lecture room 4"],
        ["14:00", "16:00", "event-2", "CO227 Labs", "drawing office I"],
      ],
      [["14:00", "16:00", "event-2", "GP106 Labs", "lab room 3"]],
      [["10:00", "12:00", "event-1", "CO227", "lecture room 14"]],
      [["15:00", "17:00", "event-2", "CO321 Labs", "lab room 4"]],
    ];

    this.setState(
      {
        timeTable: arr,
      },
      () => {
        console.log("timeTable = ", this.state.timeTable);
        this.setState({ loading: true });
      }
    );
  }
```

This change will perfectly give the timetable as it must show.

But Why this happens? I used **constructor** and **componentWillMount** instead of componentDidMount.But behaviour is the same as above.Instead of axios I used fetch().But nothing changed.I am trying this for three days and now I am hopeless.I just want to get the response from the server and set it as timetable such that it gives correct output in the website.(Not only console)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a problem but it’s kind of weird that you are setting { loading: true } separately from { timeTable: arr }.  Why not set them together?

Comment: Setting the {timeTable: arr}  requires some time to process.I wanted to make sure that {loading:true} is set after {timeTable: arr} set completely.That's why I put it on callback.Anyway I tried what you are asking.But it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out exactly what is the reason behind this.But I found out a Solution.In my website when login happens I performed an axios get Request and get the response and stored in the localStorage.When this TimeTable class is called I get the stored result from localStorage and set it in state.This worked fine in my case.I also had to clear the localStorage in logout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the values are getting into the `timeTable`, but they're not being rendered.

Could You check what happens if you use a the request somewhere else before to set a global variable `let arr = response.data.result;` then run the function `componentDidMount()`? This is in case the `axios.get()` is the one preventing to run the whole code to ender the table

So it should be something like this:

```
let timeTableArr;
let getTimeTable = () => {
    const auth = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
    FIND_LEC_SCHEDULE_URL += localStorage.getItem("lid");

    axios.get(FIND_LEC_SCHEDULE_URL, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: auth,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('response data = ',response.data);
        timeTableArr = response.data.result;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error =", error);
   });
}
componentDidMount() {
    getTimeTable();
    this.setState(
    {
      timeTable: timeTableArr,
    },
    () => {
      console.log('timeTable = ',this.state.timeTable);
      this.setState({ loading: true });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try my first approach creating a new array?

Comment: Yes.Both of them doesn't work.I am curious why ```,``` at the end of the ```response.data.result``` is so important?

Comment: Is just that's how I see all the other code including the test you did copying from Postman

Comment: I think what you're saying in Update 2 must be the real problem.I also changed the title according to that.But I do not understand what your solution is?Can you please explain it more clearly?